# web3.eth.accounts[0] returns undefined and app.vote(1,{ from:web3.eth.accounts[0] }) is giving error

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

I am new to solidity and was exploring it through a simple webapp. I'm trying to make a candidate vote web app which accepts some details and a button pressing which the details should be deployed to the block created by the smart contract. 
When I'm trying to get accounts details using `web3.eth.accounts[0]` in truffle console , it is returning undefined .
And when I'm trying to send vote to candidate 1 from account 1 using truffle console : `app.vote(1,{ from:web3.eth.accounts[0] })`, Im getting error like:

```
truffle(development)> web3.eth.accounts[0]
undefined
truffle(development)> app.vote(1,{ 
from:web3.eth.accounts[0] })
Thrown:
Error: The send transactions "from" field 
must be defined!
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:5
at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:272:15)
at Script.runInContext (vm.js:127:14)
at runScript
at bound (domain.js:426:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:439:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:726:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:219:5)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:324:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:701:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:1026:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:803:7)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:200:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:219:5)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at emitKeys (internal/readline/utils.js:438:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>) {
  hijackedStack: 'Error: The send transactions "from" field must be defined!\n' +
    '    at Method.inputTransactionFormatter (C:\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-core-helpers\\src\\formatters.js:142:1)\n' +
    '    at C:\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-core-method\\src\\index.js:144:1\n' +
    '    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at Method.formatInput (C:\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-core-method\\src\\index.js:142:1)\n' +
    '    at Method.toPayload (C:\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-core-method\\src\\index.js:177:1)\n' +
    '    at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (C:\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\web3-core-method\\src\\index.js:467:1)\n' +
    '    at Object.sendTransaction (C:\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\packages\\contract\\lib\\execute.js:486:1)\n' +
    '    at C:\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\packages\\contract\\lib\\execute.js:203:1\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this error because the from field is not defined, as you pass it `undefined`, as you can see when you run `truffle(development)> web3.eth.accounts[0]` it returns `undefined`. This is because this is an async method, meaning when you send your transaction you need to wait for the accounts method to complete.

Therefore, you should do (considering `web3.eth.accounts` is deprecated & it's tedious to type await each time):

```
truffle(development)> let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
truffle(development)> app.vote(1,{ from: accounts[0] })
```

Comment: thanks for response but ``let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
Thrown:
evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
  await web3.eth.getAccounts();
                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' ``

Comment: and ``truffle(development)> let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
undefined ``

Comment: That's normal, as the console waits for an immediate callback (which it doesn't get). Your command should have executed nonetheless - Try typing `truffle(development)> accounts` and you should see your accounts.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, it working ,can you please tell me how to vote for candidate from particular account, like : `app.vote(1,{ from: accounts[0] }) ` is not working.

Comment: Great! I think discussing this in the comments will be a little messy, so I suggest you open a new question where you show what app.vote() is supposed to do, what you're doing to invoke it, and the error message you're getting.

Comment: Hey Nicolas, I have post question for that, can you please check it .

Comment: @krishnaveer If this answered your question, please accept it so others can see.

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow the steps below.

```
$ truffle compile --reset
$ truffle migrate --reset
$ let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
$ app.vote(1,{from : accounts [2]})
```

Each time you want to vote, redo the compilation and the migration.